# Basic question on differentials and volume of a cone

Tags: integration

For no reason, I decided to proof the volume of a cone.

We choose a differential disk: $\pi r^2 dh$

Thus the volume would be: $ V = \int_0^H \pi r^2 dh$

And then for any arbitrary point in the body of the cone, it holds that: $\frac{r}{h} = \frac{R}{H}$ thus $r = \frac{R}{H} h$.

This will easily simplify to $ \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h$

What I like about this approach is that everything evens out: if we assume that $dh$ is small enough that there are no variations in the radius, then we do have a disk.

However, is it wrong to state, the disk having a height of $dh$, has two planes with radii of $r$ and $r+dr$? if this is true, the solution will work if we disregard $dr$, why can we disregard $dr$?

Follow up, can we then state: $ \frac{dh}{dr} = \frac{H}{R} $ ?(it obviously is if $dr$ and $dh$ can exist at the same time) the solution will still work out, but is it just a happy accident and is this formulation simply incorrect? or is it that it works *because* it is correct in some way that is eluding me?